# C - dynamic allocation of 2D game board of unknown dimensions

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to code a board-based game and want to represent the board as a 2D `char`-array.
In particular, the board consists of 4 different types of characters/cells:

- The player (`S`)
- The goal cell (`A`)
- Walls (`#`)
- Monsters (`^`, `v`, `<`, `>`)

Monsters look in a certain direction which is denoted by the arrow-like characters above.

I want to be able to load a Level from a text file where the following is unknown:

- the number of lines in the file (rows in a 2D-array)
- the number of chars in each line

An example Level text file:

```
    ######                                 ##########
    #  < #                                 #        #
    #    #########                         #       ##
    #    #       #                         #^      #
    #    #       #                        ##       #
  ###            #      ########        ###        #
  #     #   ######      #      ##########   #     ##
  #     #^  #           #                 #########
```

As you can see the first 3 lines have 49 chars, but the other ones contain 48/47 chars.
The difference might be much higher, so that I need to use dynamic allocation for both dimensions.

Should I read the file character-by-character or line-by-line using a fixed size buffer, extending it when necessary?

This is what I tried:

```c
int needed_num_rows = 1;
int needed_bytes_col = 16;

char **board = calloc(needed_num_rows, sizeof(char*));
char *buf = calloc(needed_bytes_col, sizeof(char));

int idx = 0;
while (fgets(buf, needed_bytes_col, level_file) != NULL) {
    if (buf[needed_bytes_col - 1] != '\n' && buf[needed_bytes_col - 1] != '\0') { // not read to the end yet
        needed_bytes_col = needed_bytes_col * 2 + 1;
        buf = realloc(buf, needed_bytes_col);
        buf += needed_bytes_col;
    } else { // whole line has been read
        if (idx + 1 > needed_num_rows) {
            needed_num_rows = needed_num_rows * 2 + 1;
            board = realloc(board, needed_num_rows);
        }

        board[idx++] = buf;
        needed_bytes_col = 16;
        buf = calloc(needed_bytes_col, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have posted?

Comment: Gives me segmentation faults, sometimes. I can't nail it down precisely. Should I instead use character-by-character processing?

Comment: This will break horribly if a line is >= (2*needed_bytes_col+1) wide, causing you to enter the expansion section *twice*. When that happens the second round `buf` is no longer pointing to a base address returned from `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, etc., or NULL, thereby violating the requirements of `realloc` and invoking *undefined behavior*. Personally, I'd rethink this and consider a [`getline/getdelim`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) solution if it is available on your platform. It would clean this up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit [too] complex with too many special cases.

It can be refactored/simplified. Easier to read the line into a fixed [maximum] size buffer and then use `strdup`

```
char **board = NULL;
size_t board_count = 0;
size_t board_max = 0;

char buf[1000];

while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),level_file) != NULL) {
    // strip newline
    buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

    // allocate more rows
    // the increment here is arbitrary -- adjust to suit
    if (board_count >= board_max) {
        board_max += 10;
        board = realloc(board,sizeof(*board) * board_max);
    }

    // store the new row
    board[board_count++] = strdup(buf);
}

// trim array to exact amount used
board = realloc(board,sizeof(*board) * board_count);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> what if line is 4000 chars long? –
> 0___________

The TL;DR is `char buf[1000000];` Of course, we can make `buf` a `char *` and do a `realloc` on it [independent of `realloc` for `board`], and reloop, but I think that's overkill in this circumstance.

**However ...**

If the board is going to be arbitrarily large (e.g millions of rows and rows that can have a million chars [or ten]), then we *could* dynamically allocate everything in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **board = NULL;
size_t board_count = 0;
size_t board_max = 0;

int
lineget(char **bufp,FILE *level_file)
{
    char *buf;
    size_t bufmax = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    char *cp;
    size_t off = 0;
    size_t remlen;
    size_t addlen;
    int valid = 0;

    buf = *bufp;

    while (1) {
        // get amount of free space remaining in buffer
        remlen = bufmax - off;

        // increase buffer length if necessary (ensure we have enough space
        // to make forward progress) -- this "lookahead" limit is arbitrary
        // as is the increment
        if (remlen < 2) {
            bufmax += 1000;
            buf = realloc(buf,bufmax);

            if (buf == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(1);
            }

            remlen = bufmax - off;
        }

        // append to the buffer
        cp = fgets(&buf[off],remlen,level_file);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        valid = 1;

        // get length of newly added chars
        addlen = strlen(&buf[off]);

        // get total length of filled area
        buflen = off + addlen;

        // check for newline and strip it and stop if we get one
        if (addlen > 0) {
            if (buf[buflen - 1] == '\n') {
                buf[--buflen] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        // increase the offset into the buffer
        off += addlen;
    }

    // trim buffer to length
    buf = realloc(buf,buflen);

    *bufp = buf;

    return valid;
}

void
readfile(void)
{

    while (1) {
        // allocate more rows
        // the increment here is arbitrary -- adjust to suit
        if (board_count >= board_max) {
            board_max += 10;
            board = realloc(board,sizeof(*board) * board_max);

            // set null pointers on unfilled rows
            for (size_t idx = board_count;  idx < board_max;  ++idx)
                board[idx] = NULL;
        }

        // fill the current row
        if (! lineget(&board[board_count],stdin))
            break;

        // advance row count
        ++board_count;
    }

    // trim array to exact amount used
    board = realloc(board,sizeof(*board) * board_count);
}
```

Comment: what if line is 4000 chars long?

Comment: @0___________ The TL;DR is `char buf[1000000];` Of course, we can make `buf` a `char *` and do a `realloc` on it [independent of `realloc` for `board`], and reloop, but I think that's overkill in this circumstance.

Comment: Just use [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).  And if you need the source because your OS doesn't support `getline()`, get it here: https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/src/vms/getline.c

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the function which reads the line of unknown size dynamically allocating buffer for it.

```
#define LINEDELTA 256

char *readline(FILE *fi)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    size_t currentSize = 0;
    if(fi)
    {
        do
        {
            char *tmp;
            tmp = realloc(result, currentSize + LINEDELTA);
            if(tmp) result = tmp;
            else { /* add error handling*/ }
            if(fgets(result + currentSize - !!currentSize, LINEDELTA + !!currentSize, fi) == (result + currentSize))
            {

            }
            else { /* add error handling*/ }
            currentSize += LINEDELTA;
        }while(strchr(result, '\n'));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dynamic memory allocation for every single line, I would recommend reading the file in two passes: Once for determining the maximum size of both dimensions, and once to actually read the data.

That way, you will know the exact memory requirements after the first pass, and can allocate a memory buffer of an appropriate size before the second pass.

One advantage of this solution is that having a fixed length in both dimensions is probably the memory representation that you will want to have after loading the game.

Therefore, I would recommend the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *level_file;
    char *board;
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t rows = 0;
    size_t cols = 0;
    size_t current_line;

    level_file = fopen( "level.txt", "rt" );
    if ( level_file == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //first pass of file to determine size of both dimensions
    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, level_file ) != NULL )
    {
        char *p;
        size_t length;

        //verify that line was not too long
        p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            //there are 3 explanations for not finding the newline character:
            //1. end-of-file was encountered
            //2. I/O error occurred
            //3. line was too long to fit in buffer

            if ( feof( level_file ) )
            {
                //make p point to terminating null character
                p = buffer + strlen( buffer );
            }
            else if ( ferror( level_file ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "I/O error occurred\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "line was too long to fit in buffer\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }

        //calculate number of columns in line
        length = p - buffer;

        //update cols to higher value, if appropriate
        if ( length > cols )
            cols = length;

        rows++;
    }

    //verify that loop terminated due to end-of-file
    if ( !feof( level_file ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error reading with fgets!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //rewind file back to start
    rewind( level_file );

    //allocate memory for board
    board = malloc( rows * cols );
    if ( board == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error allocating memory for board!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //second pass of file to actually read the data
    current_line = 0;
    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, level_file ) != NULL )
    {
        char *p;
        size_t length;

        //verify that line was not too long
        //note that it is possible that file was changed since the
        //first pass, so it is not wrong to check again (but maybe
        //not necessary)
        p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            //this is identical to first pass

            if ( feof( level_file ) )
            {
                //make p point to terminating null character
                p = buffer + strlen( buffer );
            }
            else if ( ferror( level_file ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "I/O error occurred\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "line was too long to fit in buffer\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }

        //calculate number of columns in line
        length = p - buffer;

        //verify that line consists only of valid characters
        if ( strspn(buffer," SA#^v<>") != length )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "invalid characters found in file!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that line length has not increased since first pass
        if ( length > cols )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "detected that file has changed since first pass!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //calculate start of row in board
        p = board + current_line * cols;

        //copy line contents into board
        memcpy( p, buffer, length );

        //fill rest of line with space characters
        for ( size_t i = length; i < cols; i++ )
            p[i] = ' ';

        //increment loop counter
        current_line++;
    }

    //verify that loop terminated due to end-of-file
    if ( !feof( level_file ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error reading with fgets!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fclose( level_file );

    printf( "rows: %d, cols: %d\n\n", rows, cols );

    //print board contents
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            putchar( board[i*cols+j] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( board );
}
```

I have tested this program successfully with the following input file:

```
   # S A v <
   #### ## A
AAA ###
```

Note, however, that this program only supports lines up to `1022` characters (`1024` including the newline and terminating null character), due to the following declaration:

`char buffer[1024];`

Although it is possible to increase this size, it is generally a bad idea to allocate more than a few kilobytes on the stack, as this could cause a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). Therefore, if it is possible for a single line to be larger than a few kilobytes, then it would be appropriate to allocate `buffer` somewhere else than the stack, for example by using dynamic memory allocation instead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit complicated however you look at it. I used `mmap()` and a line parsing function. This function does only the newline finding, plus skip repeated ones and check the length. The idea was to have three returns: -1 = finished, -2 = skip this line, positive = use this line (or use the second parameter e.g. a struct).

So even if one parses only the lines' existence and length, it still is some kind of parsing. The main part is:

```
plret = parse_lines(&pmap)
```

`pmap` is the moving copy of the `mmap()` mapping. `parse_lines()` advances it. `plret` tells you whether to 1) stop 2) continue or 3) act and continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

/* file must have NL at end, and memory a \0 */
int parse_lines(char **pmap) {

    int const maxline = 60;
    char *map = *pmap;
    while(*map == '\n')            //skip empty lines??? 
        map++;

    if (! *map)
        return -1;                 // means EOF 

    char *nnl = strchr(map, '\n');  
    *pmap = nnl + 1;               // new position for caller: start of next line

    if (nnl - map < maxline) 
        return nnl - map;          // return length of line  
    else
        return -2;                 // too long  
}
void parse_file() {
    char const *f = "test";
    size_t const mmlen = 256*256;                     // or fstat()

    int fd = open(f, O_RDONLY);
    char *mapping = mmap(0, mmlen, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0),
         *pmap = mapping;  
    
    int plret;
    while ((plret = parse_lines(&pmap)) != -1) 

        if (plret > 0) {

            char *s = calloc(plret+1, 1);
            memcpy(s, pmap-plret-1, plret);           // NL (+1) or not? 

            printf("%d at %p now %p:\t\"%s\"\n", plret, pmap, s, s);
            free(s);                                  // rather store it in an array
        } 
        else
            printf("line too long - skip or truncate or abort\n"); 

    /* End of File */
    munmap(mapping, mmlen);
    // + realloc array for @s-pointers, if it was allocated "big enough"
}
int main(void) {
    parse_file();
}
```

I left out the array `arr[idx++] = s` (without the checking/realloc). But the output illustrates nicely what is going on (the third to last line is extra long):

```
53 at 0x7fdc29283036 now 0x5557230822a0:        "    ######                                 ##########"
53 at 0x7fdc2928306c now 0x5557230826f0:        "    #  < #                                 #        #"
53 at 0x7fdc292830a2 now 0x555723082730:        "    #    #########                         #       ##"
52 at 0x7fdc292830d7 now 0x555723082770:        "    #    #       #                         #^      #"
52 at 0x7fdc2928310c now 0x5557230827b0:        "    #    #       #                        ##       #"
52 at 0x7fdc29283141 now 0x5557230827f0:        "  ###            #      ########        ###        #"
52 at 0x7fdc29283176 now 0x555723082830:        "  #     #   ######      #      ##########   #     ##"
51 at 0x7fdc292831aa now 0x555723082870:        "  #     #^  #           #                 #########"
line too long - skip or truncate or abort
2 at 0x7fdc292831fd now 0x5557230828b0: "##"
1 at 0x7fdc292831ff now 0x5557230828d0: "#"
```

The bytes at 0x7fd... found a new home as strings at 0x555...

They lost the newline but now have a null terminator.